# attr_accessor for array?

Tags: ruby

I want to have an array as a instance variable using `attr_accessor`.

But isn't `attr_accessor` only for strings?

How do I use it on an array?

UPDATE:

Eg. If you want:

```
object.array = "cat"
object.array = "dog"
pp object.array
=> ["cat", "dog"]
```

Then you have to create those methods yourself?

Comment: attr_accessor works for any object. Have you tried it? What went wrong?

Comment: @Douglas: Look at update

Comment: If you define a method `foo=` so that after doing `x.foo = bar`, `x.foo` does not return `bar`, you'll confuse the heck out of anybody who uses your class. Why not just do `object.array << "cat"`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Re your update:

Although you can implement a class which acts as you describe, it is quite unusual, and will probably confuse anyone using the class.

Normally accessors have setters and getters. When you set something using the setter, you get the same thing back from the getter. In the example below, you get something totally different back from the getter. Instead of using a setter, you should probably use an `add` method.

```
class StrangePropertyAccessorClass

  def initialize
    @data = []
  end

  def array=(value)   # this is bad, use the add method below instead
    @data.push(value)
  end

  def array
    @data
  end

end

object = StrangePropertyAccessorClass.new

object.array = "cat"
object.array = "dog"
pp object.array
```

The add method would look like this:

```
  def add(value)
    @data.push(value)
  end

...

object.add "cat"
object.add "dog"
pp object.array
```

Comment: +1 for giving an explanation. I also like the << method. So you can write object.array << "cat" instead of push. This is only one character more than object.array = "cat" .

Comment: Yeah, also it makes sense at all, unlike `object.array = "cat"`, which is completely batty.

Answer (score 22):

```
class SomeObject
  attr_accessor :array

  def initialize
    self.array = []
  end
end

o = SomeObject.new

o.array.push :a
o.array.push :b
o.array << :c
o.array.inspect   #=> [:a, :b, :c]
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize() 
    @arr = [1,2,3]
  end

end

f = Foo.new
p f.arr
```

Returns the following

```
$ ruby /tmp/t.rb
[1, 2, 3]
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a case for this usage. Consider

```
begin
  result = do_something(obj)
  # I can't handle the thought of failure, only one result matters!
  obj.result = result
rescue
  result = try_something_else(obj)
  # okay so only this result matters!
  obj.result = result
end
```

And then later

```
# We don't really care how many times we tried only the last result matters
obj.result
```

And then for the pro's we have

```
# How many times did we have to try?
obj.results.count
```

So, I would:

```
attr_accessor :results

def initialize
  @results = []
end

def result=(x)
  @results << x
end

def result
  @results.last
end
```

In this way `result` behaves as you would expect, but you also get the benefit of accessing the past values.