# Set non-database attribute for rails model without `attr_accessor`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In PHP, I can set an attribute (that is not a column in database) to a model. E.g.(PHP code),

```
$user = new User;
$user->flag = true;
```

But in rails, when I set any attribute that doesn't exist in database, it will throw an error `undefined method flag`. There is `attr_accessor` method, but what will happen if I need about ten temp attributes?

Comment: Having non column attributes in the object is a code smell, at least for me. Here something related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvL_aZt3zyU

Comment: You wouldn't normally use $-variables in rails.  Are you mixing php and ruby code together there?

Comment: @MaxWilliams No, that is a PHP example.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying "How do i do this in rails?"?  That's not clear, to me at least.

Comment: @MaxWilliams oh, I'm sorry because make the example not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected because it's how ActiveRecord works by design. If you need to set arbitrary attributes, then you have to use a different kind of objects.

For example, Ruby provides a library called [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) that allows you to create objects where you can assign arbitrary key/values. You may want to use such library and then convert the object into a corresponding ActiveRecord instance only if/when you need to save to the database.

Don't try to model `ActiveRecord` to behave as you just described because it was simply not designed to behave in that way. That would be a [cargo culting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) error from your current PHP knowledge.

Comment: thank a lot, I never know `OpenStruct` lib until you told me. I combined your solution with @Nimir solution and it work perfectly :D
`attr_accessor :flag

after_initialize do |user|
    self.flag = OpenStruct.new
end`
And I can set/get the temp flag attribute by using
`@user.flag.hello = "Hello World"`

ps: sr, I don't know how to format the code

Answer (score 22):

> but what will happen if I need about ten temp attributes?

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :flag, :other_attribute, :other_attribute2, :etc...
end
```

[`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) creates ["virtual" attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) in Rails -- they don't exist in the database, but are present in the model.

As with attributes from the db, `attr_accessor` just creates a set of `setter` & `getter` (instance) methods in your class, which you can call & interact with when the class is initialized:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :flag

   # getter
   def flag
     @flag
   end

   # setter
   def flag=(val)
     @flag = val
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As the guys explained, `attr_accessor` is just a quick `setter` and `getter`.

We can set our Model attr_accessor on record initializing to be a [Ruby#Hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) for example using [ActiveRecord#After_initilize method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) so we get more flexibility on temporarily storing values ([idea credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693316/903842)).

Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :vars

  after_initialize do |user|
    self.vars = Hash.new
  end

end
```

Now you could do:

```
user = User.new

#set
user.vars['flag'] = true

#get
user.vars['flag']
#> true
```

Answer (score 2):

All that attr_accessor does is add getter and setter methods which use an instance variable, eg this

```
attr_accessor :flag
```

will add these methods:

```
def flag
  @flag
end

def flag=(val)
  @flag = val
end
```

You can write these methods yourself if you want, and have them do something more interesting than just storing the value in an instance var, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need temp attributes you can add them to the singleton object.

```
instance = Model.new

class << instance
  attr_accessor :name
end
```